# How to set maximum index value in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to have the index value in a range like 100 to 200 instead of 0 to upper limit as per column type int.

For the lower limit while creating the table I used `[ID] [int] IDENTITY(100, 1) NOT NULL` however I am not able figure out how to achieve the upper limit of 200.

How to achieve this?

Regards

Comment: what does this mean? it should refuse inserts with ID bigger than 200?

Comment: yes, Luis it should refuse with an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a check contraint

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT id_limits CHECK (id between 100 and 200)
```

Comment: i was thinking totally in a different perspective something similar to start index and seed value of index... and forgot the basic feature column constraint ... shame on me..

Answer (score -1):

You can create a trigger to do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpperLimit
ON ExistingTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT ID
        FROM INSERTED
        WHERE ID > 200
    )
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
    END
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger is dangerous: it silently rollbacks an `INSERT` without telling the application. At least raise an error.

Comment: And it will rollback all rows for a multiple row operation. A check constraint is a MUCH better choice here.